# How to autofill excel cells between a range using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do we autofill cells in Microsoft Excel through **formula** between `0 to 1000` and `each 50 step` ?

i mean **0 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500 550 600 650 700 750 800 850 900 950 1000**

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Wouldn't simply adding 50 to the previous cell do the trick?

Comment: @Jerry: I knew if i set first cell to `0` and next cell to `50` with hold and release mouse i could do it. but as i said in the question, im trying to generate it automatically. that's why i asked about is there any way to use formula to generate it? let me know if there is any way to use VBA to generate it automatically

Comment: Well, 'automatically' is quite ambiguous. If it's completely automatic, the sheet would be filled with numbers before you can do anything... What is supposed to trigger the function?

Comment: Yeah, Exactly as you said it be completely automatic and the sheet would be filled with numbers before we can do anything. actually just automatic generate numbers between `0` to `1000` with `50 step` and then fill automatic in cells.

Comment: Okay, that's not something a formula can do. I'm not sure how templates work, but I guess it's worth a research if you can open new worksheets with those numbers already generated and if that would suit you.

Comment: What about VBA? through `For`

Comment: Oh yea, VBA should work too I guess, but I don't know VBA as much as I'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
first field with 0 and the second field with 50.
mark both cells and click on the black square bottom right. 
with pressed mouse move down. release mouse. then click on the small dialog which appears and change in the setting the steps.

Comment: This way is not like i asked in the question. Read first comment in post1 at current topic. thank you